# Why am I not getting a value from my getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, html, url, getelementbyid

I want to take in a value from the URL, add it to a span tag on my slots.html so the user can read it, then pull that same value into another JS file to alter it as the game progresses. The Url code works fine and I get the appropriate value:

`elId("wallet").textContent = (values["bank"]);` which returns for example 1234.

`<p>Player Bank: <span id="wallet"></span></p>` which displays 1234 properly

but when I try to get the value from my html (`var elWallet=elId("wallet");`)to another JS page it returns `<span id="wallet"></span>` instead of 1234.

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong, and how to improve my understanding of this. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: `var elId = function(id) {return document.getElementById(id); }` is the function I wrote to make writing document.get easier.

EDIT 2: Well I found the issue, talking through with a friend, thanks anyways for all the help.

Comment: You assigned to its `textContent` property, but you didn’t read its `textContent` property.

Comment: Is elId a function you wrote? If so can you post it.

Comment: I am sorry, I am quite new to JavaScript, could you please elaborate?, also added the function! I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Could please try using innerHTML to get the values.

elWallet.innerHTML will return the value inside your span tag.

Update: 
This works for me. may be you might have put wallet element after the script tag.

Player Bank: 1234

```
<script>
var elId = function(id) {return document.getElementById(id); }
var elWallet=elId("wallet");
console.log(elWallet.textContent);
console.log(elWallet.innerHTML);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try reordering your script to the bottom of the page. before html or body